# How to stream reads in Couchbase

Tags: c#, couchbase

I want to stream a set of documents from a query in Couchbase using a single query. The problem is this could return a a couple of million of documents and so I want to get them gradually from Couchbase, do some light processing and then write the result to a file stream, thus saving me from loading the whole result set into memory. Does anyone know if this is possible in Couchbase?

edit: sorry, forgot to say I'm trying to do this in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only way to do that directly is to use paging on the query to retrieve the results in chunks. This comes with the obvious downside of the result set (potentially) changing between page retrievals, if you have some other process that continues to change data in the background. In C# it would look something like this (typing from memory, apologies if it doesn't compile straightaway):

```
var pageSize = 100;
var pageIndex = 0
IQueryResult<dynamic> result = null;

do {
    var query = string.Format("SELECT myBucket.* FROM myBucket LIMIT {0} OFFSET {1}", pageSize, pageIndex);
    result = await bucket.QueryAsync<dynamic>(query);

    pageIndex += result.Rows != null ? result.Rows.Count : 0;
}
while(result.Success && result.Rows.Count > 0);
```

Your other option is to copy the result of the desired query into another, presumably empty, bucket and then query/page through them at your leisure, because the copy will not be affected by changes to the original bucket:

```
INSERT INTO otherBucket (key _k, value _v) 
SELECT META().ID _k, _v FROM myBucket _v WHERE <your conditions here>;
```

Follow this up with the paging code described earlier.

Comment: I was worried that would be the case.